# Display the Latest Date and Time

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

Goal:
Display the value of the latest date and time of the cube's process in SSRS

Problem:
Based on the code below, I can retrieve the data in SQL server mgnt studio but when I'm inside of the Query Designer in SSRS I cannot retrieve the data based on the same sourcecode.

Source code:

```
SELECT * FROM $system.mdschema_cubes
WHERE CUBE_NAME = 'aaaaaa'
```

Comment: I understand your problem is that you do not know how to get Reporting Services to accept the query you state as input. Is this correct? Then you should tag your query with ReportingServices as well.

Comment: "I understand your problem is that you do not know how to get Reporting Services to accept the query you state as input. Is this correct?" yes, it is correct.         "I understand your problem is that you do not know how to get Reporting Services to accept the query you state as input. Is this correct?" What do you mean?

Comment: My assumption was that your question is more one how to get Reporting Services to accept your query than a question about MDX, as you already had the query. Hence I suggested to tag your query with `SSRS`. Anyway, @mmarie's answer describes a way to get SSRS to accept the statement.

Comment: Q. "My assumption was that your question is more one how to get Reporting Services to accept your query than a question about MDX, as you already had the query" A. Yes, that is right answer. I still have problem to retrieve the latest date and time in SSRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the datetime of last processing:

```
SELECT LAST_DATA_UPDATE FROM $system.mdschema_cubes WHERE CUBE_NAME = 'aaaaaa'
```

To use this query in SSRS, you need to create a data set with an SSRS data source.  Then [switch the command type to DMX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155812.aspx).  You can then click the icon to edit as text and paste your query. Click OK and your data set fields will populate in the report data pane and you can be on your way.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was enable to retrieve the latest date and time and when I reprocessed the cube, I was not enable to retrieve the latest date and time. I retrieved the previous latest date and time in SSRS. How should I enable to do?

Comment: I was enable to find the answer. You need to make a new selection in the parameter to update autmoatic.